# JAVA .dat seems to be reset

Tags: java, serialization

So I have a group of serializable objects that I am storing in a single serializable object. This is saved in a hierarchy:

User -> Album -> Photo (where each is serialized with a different number )

For some reason the program performs as expected when adding user and albums. However, when adding photos, everything seems to work alright until I attempt to save. At this point, I get an IOException. The strange thing is that it is the same directory as the other working configurations and I am not saving anywhere else (only 1 time). When I open the .dat file, it seems to have grown in size by around 100 lines and still exists at that spot. There is an IOexception occurring after we add a photo and then try to write the UserList to the .dat file. The only thing I can think of is that there is some sort of size limit issue? Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have just figured it out. It seems that because I have static classes (for the purpose of being used as comparators) inside of my other classes, they also need to implement Serializable. This seems to have fixed my issue.